# How to normalise a relation using functional dependencies

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

```
G = {{A,B}→{C},{B,D}→{E,F},{A,D}→{G,H},{A}→{I},{H}→{J} }.
```

Which is a key attribute: `{A,B}` or `{A,B,D}`?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to check if a set of attributes is a key, is to compute the closure of those attributes with respect to the functional dependencies, and see if this contains all the attributes of the relation.

So:

{A B}<sup>+</sup> = {A B C I}

{A B D}<sup>+</sup> = {A B C D E F G H I J}

And so {A B D} is a key. You can also see that *every* key must contain A B D since those attributes appear only in the left parts of the dependencies, and since {A B D} by themselves are a key, there are no other keys.